# Resigned from my position on UK Tier 2 Visa: Do I need to notify UK Visas and Immigration that I have left the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

I was a UK tier 2 visa holder from Australia. I resigned from my position and returned **permanently** to Australia three months ago.

I have just received an email with a "Notice of Curtailment" regarding my UK tier 2 visa, informing me that I have to leave the UK by a given date (or submit a new application).

Should I send them a letter saying that I already left? Are you suppose to notify them when you leave?

Comment: related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5504/how-to-terminate-a-uk-tier-2-visa

Answer (score 4):

You do not have to reply to a curtailment notice, and they have no facility to store your reply in the first instance.  As long as you are gone by the curtailment date, you will have acquitted yourself of any further obligation.

If you are still in the UK when your curtailment arrives, read [this](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5504/how-to-terminate-a-uk-tier-2-visa/5512#5512).

If you apply for a visa in the future, you will asked to enter your previous dates in the UK and you can provide the information then.

Some people send them a reply anyway because it adds to their comfort, and nothing prevents your posting a letter.

Later this year, they will begin implementing exit checks, and computer records will exist from that point.

Answer (score 2):

No need to send the letter i believe but you must send back your BRP card.

> If you hold a biometric residence permit (BRP), you are required to return it to the Home
>   Office. BRPs should be cut into quarters and sent to: BRP Management Unit, Home Office,
>   Conference House, Portishead Office Park, Conference Avenue, Portishead, Bristol BS20 7LZ,
>   Great Britain.
>   You may be issued with a fine of up to £1,000 should you fail to send your BRP to the Home
>   Office.

Comment: Opps. I probably should have done that a while ago.

Comment: Can I leave and send it from whatever country I am in? How will I know that they received it?