# Which governmental bodies to inform if leaving UK

Tags: united-kingdom, relocation

My family and I are leaving the UK. Which governmental bodies must I inform about this?

Comment: Are you a UK citizen, if not, what UK visa are you on.

Comment: @StrongBad, we are on Tier 2 visas.

Comment: Related  http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5504/how-to-terminate-a-uk-tier-2-visa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GOV.UK has a webpage about moving abroad: https://www.gov.uk/moving-or-retiring-abroad

In short, you will have to inform

- your local council
- relevant benefits offices
- the International Pension Centre
- HM Revenue and Customs (HMRC)