# What are the steps to leave the UK on a skilled worker visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, relocation

I am planning to leave UK and I am on a skilled worker visa. The steps that I have understood are -

**My responsibilities -**

1. Send a copy of the resignation to UKVI. Include your proposed leaving date

Is this the UKVI email - public.enquiries@homeoffice.gov.uk?

**My employers' responsibilities** -

1. Have to inform Home office (UKVI) of my resignation within 1**0 days of my resignation letter to the UKVI**

Is this correct? Please let me know.

This thread is the closest to my question but is 8 years old - [How to terminate a UK tier 2 visa?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5504/how-to-terminate-a-uk-tier-2-visa)

Comment: You are correct regarding your employer’s responsibilities per C1.12 in https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/workers-and-temporary-workers-guidance-for-sponsors-part-3-sponsor-duties-and-compliance/workers-and-temporary-workers-guidance-for-sponsors-part-3-sponsor-duties-and-compliance-accessible-version AFAIK you can use a Change of Circumstances form to report your resignation to UKVI https://www.gov.uk/change-circumstances-visa-brp/youre-in-the-uk-and-dont-have-a-brp

Comment: Thanks @Traveller - Anything else that I should know? Also, is the email correct?

Comment: UKVI is part of the Home Office, but the ‘public enquiries’ email you mention doesn’t seem appropriate to me. I would use the online ‘change of circumstances’ form if I were you. Other info you need to know is that you must leave the UK by the date given in the curtailment/cancellation letter from UKVI (this can have immediate effect, or otherwise typically within 60 days).